# Springs Simple <remember-me/> not working :-(

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, remember-me

I am trying to make use of Spring Security's [`<remember-me/>` authentification](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.htmlmm). The line in my security context looks like this:

```
 <security:remember-me key="89dqj219dn910lsAc12" user-service-ref="jpaUserDetailsService"/>
```

Although I use my own implementation of `UserDetailsService` (tested & working), I have also tried with the default one running into the same issue, which is this:

1. Logging in with "remember-me" checkbox checked, a cookie is generated as expected:

   Name: SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE; Value: c2FzczoxMjg1NTIxOTI1NzY4OmIxODQ5YTE2ZDY1MDVmZDFhNWRlN2Y2NzFlMzc1MmI0; Host: localhost; Path: /webapp; Secure: No; Valid until: Sun, 26 Sep 2010 17:25:25 GMT)
2. The browser restarted
3. The cookie is still there
4. Trying to access any secured page ends in "Access denied" error:

   org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

   Authentication object as a String: org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@ffcaab94: Principal: de.myapp.businessobjects.AppUser@35c12e: Username: username; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; PersonalInformation: 32768; ; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities

I am confused an do not know what goes wrong or where to start debugging. Help, please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like user is successfully authenticated, but for some reason he has no authorities (i.e. roles). So, make sure that user details returned by your `UserDetailsService` returns proper authorities from `UserDetails.getAuthorities()`.

Comment: Ahh ... great hint! You are right, I forgot to test my UserDetailsService.getAuthorities() implementation - voila, it actually *is* buggy. Thanks!

Comment: O dear, I am sorry. I mocked roles but still getting a similar error: "... SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER" Pitty. BTW, why is SessionId `null` anyway?

Comment: @erlord: I don't think sessionid is an issue. This looks like a regular `AccessDeniedException`, perhaps `ROLE_USER` is not enough to perform the requested action.

Comment: If so, why does it work in first place, i.e. when logging in? The same URL works *before* restart and fails *after* ... do I have to assign roles to <remember-me/> something?